# Setting bound constraints in L-BFGS?

Tags: optimization

How does one choose the bounding constraints for the parameters in L-BFGS? Should these be viewed as a hyperparameter to be chosen subject to a criteria or do they arise as constraints in the typical "optimize/subject to" way of writing  the problem?

Comment: The latter; they arise as constraints in the typical "optimize / subject to" way of writing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds define the range for the optimized parameter that is to be searched. You set them based on the reasonable range that the optimized parameter can take, or $(-\infty, \infty)$ if you don't have idea for the range. Usually, if the optimized parameters are not constrained (e.g. need to be non-negative) you don't use the bounds.

Comment: thank you for this . Great answer!